# Manufacturing Custom Raspberry Pi ProtoType

Tags: hardware, audio

I'm looking for some general suggestions as to where I could go to get a custom Raspberry Pi / Beagle Bone Black or similar hardware created but with customizations. Basically I'm looking for a device which has everything that a PI or BBB has, but I need more audio inputs directly added to the board and the ability to input very high quality audio. These inputs need to be added directly to the Raspberry Pi and can't be added via a PiHat because I would eventually like to manufacture this device with embedded software.

I understand that Element14 does this for larger orders between 3000-5000 ($100k+), but I can't cut that and am just looking for a proof of concept with the understand that it would be a premium, but still way cheaper then $100k+.

Comment: Only the manufacturers can "add" to the board.  They are not going to tool up an assembly line for a run of a few off.  You might have to rethink.

Comment: The usual way to do this is making a custom hat. You don't need to be ashamed you have to buy a Pi and plug it into your board. In contrary, I consider this a good design using well supported standard components instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I could possibly use a Pi Hat for a POC, but I definitely cannot ask customers to be technical in an capacity.

Comment: Huh? Your customers don't buy your board and a Pi. They buy an assembled device from you, including the Pi, your board, a casing, a power supply etc.

Comment: That could possibly work. In which case I would still need someone to build out the Pi Hat, which alters this question a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hat approach is acceptable, then there are various audio hats and addons on the market which can solve your problems. Take at look at this incomplete short list at [eLinux](https://elinux.org/RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound).